# How to remove HighCharts new Hover Effect?

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts released a new version (I believe 7.1) and as a result whenever you hover over a certain element on a graph, the rest of the elements lighten in color.

I want to remove this effect and have the elements not lighten in color and still be visible to the user.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried this and this is not what I need or at least it doesn't remove the effect that I am talking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This new hover effect is called the **inactive state**. You can disable it by setting `plotOptions.series.states.inactive.opacity = 1`.

**Code:**

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      states: {
        inactive: {
          opacity: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/34m7k0f2/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.states.inactive